# How to show current date and time on an image

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, html5-canvas

When I capture an image, I want it to show the current date and time. I've used canvas, but that does not give me an acceptable result. How can I do this using Cordova?

Comment: can you provide more info and code of your "unacceptable" problem?